# Another beautiful integral (Part 2)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, harmonic-numbers

One of the ways of calculating the integral in closed form is to think of crafitly using the geometric series, but even so it seems evil enough.

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{1}{(1+x) (1+y) (1+z)(1+w) (1+ x y z w)} \ dx \ dy \ dz \ dw$$

Maybe you can guide me, bless me with another *precious* hints, clues. Thanks MSE users!

*Supplementary question*: How about the generalization?

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\cdots\int_0^1\frac{1}{(1+x_1) (1+x_2)\cdots  (1+x_n)(1+ x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n)} \ dx_1 \ dx_2 \cdots \ dx_n$$

Comment: maple cannot go further than two integrations, at that point giving a complicated expression involving dilogarithms. It just returns the third integration attempt as a symbolic restatement of the integration (having the last variable inside it as a remaining parameter).

Comment: @coffeemath also with *Mathematica* things become pretty complicated after $2$ integrations.The cases $n=2, 3$ are easy, but when dealing with $n\ge4$ the job to do is pretty difficult.

Comment: This is equivalent to $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n (\log 2 -H_{n^{-}})^4$            where $\displaystyle H_{n^{-}}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}=\log 2+(-1)^{n+1}\int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{1+x}dx$ are skew  (alternating) harmonic numbers. the squared case was discussed [here.](https://www.sav.sk/journals/uploads/0123134909Boyadz.pdf)

Comment: @nospoon: I agree with you. The computation of such a series looks like just a tedious exercise in summation by parts.

Comment: @nospoon very nice paper. Thanks (+1)

Comment: @Chris'ssistheartist in which way this integral looks beautiful? For me it just looks like a total mess ;-)

Comment: @tired maybe there are very nice and short ways to do it. I feel I miss a nice way to go. Still working on it here.

Comment: @nospoon Try to add some spaces in the text and it will be fixed.

Comment: Meanwhile i reduced it to:
$$\small \frac52\zeta(3)\ln2 - \frac{11\pi^4}{576}  -\frac{\pi^2}{12}\ln^2 2 + \frac{\ln^4 2}{16} + \frac32 \operatorname{Li_4}\left(\frac12\right)-\int_0^1 \frac{ \operatorname{Li}_3(x) }{1+x} dx + \frac12 \int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x^2) \operatorname{Li_2} \left(\frac{1-x}{2}\right)}{x}dx$$                            If there indeed a very nice and short way to do it, alot of stuff should cancel here.. (Thanks, Chris.)

Comment: @nospoon you made a lot of progress. Good job!(+1)

Comment: @nospoon: I believe I have found the closed forms of your two integrals. Kindly see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3233291/more-on-the-integral-int-01-int-01-int-01-int-01-frac11x-1y-1z).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This response will only address the $n=4$ case,

$$I_{4}:=\int_{[0,1]^{4}}\frac{\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z\,\mathrm{d}w}{\left(1+x\right)\left(1+y\right)\left(1+z\right)\left(1+w\right)\left(1+xyzw\right)}.\tag{1}$$

According to WolframAlpha, the multiple integral $(1)$ above has the approximate numerical value $I_{4}\approx0.223076.$

Starting with the substitution $w=\frac{1-t}{1+xyzt}$, we can whittle the multiple integral down to the following double integral:

$$\begin{align}
I_{4}
&=\small{\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}z\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}w}{\left(1+x\right)\left(1+y\right)\left(1+z\right)\left(1+w\right)\left(1+xyzw\right)}}\\
&=\small{\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}z\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\left(1+x\right)\left(1+y\right)\left(1+z\right)\left(2-t+xyzt\right)}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}z\,\frac{\ln{(2)}-\ln{\left(1+xyz\right)}}{\left(1+x\right)\left(1+y\right)\left(1+z\right)\left(1-xyz\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{xy}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{2}{1+v}\right)}}{\left(1+x\right)\left(1+y\right)\left(xy+v\right)\left(1-v\right)};~~~\small{\left[xyz=v\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{d}u\int_{0}^{u}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{2}{1+v}\right)}}{\left(1+x\right)\left(x+u\right)\left(u+v\right)\left(1-v\right)};~~~\small{\left[xy=u\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{d}v\int_{v}^{x}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{2}{1+v}\right)}}{\left(1+x\right)\left(x+u\right)\left(u+v\right)\left(1-v\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\int_{v}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{v}^{x}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{2}{1+v}\right)}}{\left(1+x\right)\left(x+u\right)\left(u+v\right)\left(1-v\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\int_{v}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\int_{u}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{2}{1+v}\right)}}{\left(1+x\right)\left(x+u\right)\left(u+v\right)\left(1-v\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\int_{v}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{(1+u)^2}{4u}\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{2}{1+v}\right)}}{\left(1-u\right)\left(u+v\right)\left(1-v\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\int_{0}^{u}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{(1+u)^2}{4u}\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{2}{1+v}\right)}}{\left(1-u\right)\left(u+v\right)\left(1-v\right)}.\tag{2}\\
\end{align}$$

WolframAlpha's numerical approximation of the iterated integral obtained in the last line of $(2)$ is consistent with the original approximation stated above, so I am reasonably confident that I haven't made any errors so far.

Continuing, transforming variables and changing the order of integration yields the following equivalent double integral representation of $I_{4}$:

$$\begin{align}
I_{4}
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\int_{0}^{u}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{(1+u)^2}{4u}\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{2}{1+v}\right)}}{\left(1-u\right)\left(u+v\right)\left(1-v\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\int_{\frac{1-u}{1+u}}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{(1+u)^2}{4u}\right)}\ln{\left(1+y\right)}}{\left(1-u\right)\left(u+\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right)y\left(1+y\right)};~~~\small{\left[\frac{1-v}{1+v}=y\right]}\\
&=-\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{x}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1-x^2\right)}\ln{\left(1+y\right)}}{xy\left(1-xy\right)};~~~\small{\left[\frac{1-u}{1+u}=x\right]}\\
&=-\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{y}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln{\left(1-x^2\right)}\ln{\left(1+y\right)}}{xy\left(1-xy\right)}.\tag{3}\\
\end{align}$$

Now, the dilogarithm function $\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(z\right)}$ for complex argument is traditionally defined via the integral representation

$$\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(z\right)}:=-\int_{0}^{z}\frac{\ln{\left(1-t\right)}}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t;~~~\small{z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus(1,\infty)}.\tag{4}$$

The following indefinite integral may then be confirmed by differentiated both sides of the equation:

$$\small{\int\frac{\ln{\left(c+dx\right)}}{a+bx}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{b\left(c+dx\right)}{bc-ad}\right)}+\ln{\left(c+dx\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{d\left(a+bx\right)}{ad-bc}\right)}}{b}+\color{grey}{constant}.}\tag{5}$$

Next, splitting up the logarithm function of $x$ in the numerator and applying partial fraction decomposition to the rational part, we find

$$\begin{align}
I_{4}
&=-\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{y}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln{\left(1-x^2\right)}\ln{\left(1+y\right)}}{xy\left(1-xy\right)}\\
&=-\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{y}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+x\right)}\ln{\left(1+y\right)}}{xy\left(1-xy\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{y}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln{\left(1-x\right)}\ln{\left(1+y\right)}}{xy\left(1-xy\right)}\\
&=-\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\ln{\left(1+y\right)}\int_{0}^{y}\mathrm{d}x\,\left[\frac{1}{1-xy}+\frac{1}{xy}\right]\ln{\left(1+x\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\ln{\left(1+y\right)}\int_{0}^{y}\mathrm{d}x\,\left[\frac{1}{1-xy}+\frac{1}{xy}\right]\ln{\left(1-x\right)}\\
&=-\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\ln{\left(1+y\right)}\int_{0}^{y}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+x\right)}}{1-xy}\\
&~~~~~-\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+y\right)}}{y}\int_{0}^{y}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+x\right)}}{x}\\
&~~~~~-\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\ln{\left(1+y\right)}\int_{0}^{y}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln{\left(1-x\right)}}{1-xy}\\
&~~~~~-\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+y\right)}}{y}\int_{0}^{y}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln{\left(1-x\right)}}{x}\\
&=\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+y\right)}}{y}\left[-\int_{0}^{y}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{y\ln{\left(1+x\right)}}{1-xy}\right]\\
&~~~~~+\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+y\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-y\right)}}{y}\\
&~~~~~-\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\ln{\left(1+y\right)}\int_{1-y}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln{\left(t\right)}}{1-y\left(1-t\right)};~~~\small{\left[1-x=t\right]}\\
&~~~~~+\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+y\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(y\right)}}{y}\\
&=\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+y\right)}}{y}\left[\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(y\right)}+\ln{\left(1-y\right)}\ln{\left(1+y\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{y}{1+y}\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~-\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+y\right)}}{y}\int_{1-y}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)\ln{\left(t\right)}}{1+\left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)t}\\
&~~~~~+\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+y\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-y\right)}}{y}+\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+y\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(y\right)}}{y}\\
&=\small{\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+y\right)}}{y}\left[\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(y\right)}+\ln{\left(1-y\right)}\ln{\left(1+y\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-y\right)}+\frac12\ln^{2}{\left(1+y\right)}\right]}\\
&~~~~~\small{-\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+y\right)}}{y}\left[\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{y}{y-1}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-y\right)}-\ln{\left(1-y\right)}\ln{\left(1+y\right)}\right]}\\
&~~~~~+\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+y\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-y\right)}}{y}+\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+y\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(y\right)}}{y}\\
&=\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+y\right)}}{y}\left[\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(y\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-y\right)}+\ln{\left(1-y\right)}\ln{\left(1+y\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~+\frac14\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln^{3}{\left(1+y\right)}}{y}\\
&~~~~~\small{+\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+y\right)}}{y}\left[\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(y\right)}+\frac12\ln^{2}{\left(1-y\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-y\right)}+\ln{\left(1-y\right)}\ln{\left(1+y\right)}\right]}\\
&~~~~~+\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+y\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-y\right)}}{y}+\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+y\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(y\right)}}{y}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+y\right)}}{y}\left[\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(y\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-y\right)}+\ln{\left(1-y\right)}\ln{\left(1+y\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~+\frac14\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln^{3}{\left(1+y\right)}}{y}+\frac14\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(1-y\right)}\ln{\left(1+y\right)}}{y}\\
&~~~~~+\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+y\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-y\right)}}{y}+\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+y\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(y\right)}}{y}\\
&=\frac32\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+y\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(y\right)}}{y}+\frac32\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+y\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-y\right)}}{y}\\
&~~~~~+\frac14\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln^{3}{\left(1+y\right)}}{y}+\frac14\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(1-y\right)}\ln{\left(1+y\right)}}{y}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1-y\right)}\ln^{2}{\left(1+y\right)}}{y}.\tag{6}\\
\end{align}$$

And so we have reduced our multiple integral to a sum of five single-variable polylogarithmic integrals. Instead of attempting to evaluate each of these in turn, we'll save much energy if we make a few rearrangements first.

$$\begin{align}
I_{4}
&=\frac32\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+y\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(y\right)}}{y}+\frac32\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+y\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-y\right)}}{y}\\
&~~~~~+\frac14\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln^{3}{\left(1+y\right)}}{y}+\frac14\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(1-y\right)}\ln{\left(1+y\right)}}{y}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1-y\right)}\ln^{2}{\left(1+y\right)}}{y}\\
&=\frac32\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+y\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-y\right)}}{y}+\frac32\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+y\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(y\right)}}{y}\\
&~~~~~+\frac14\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln^{3}{\left(1+y\right)}}{y}+\frac14\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(1-y\right)}\ln{\left(1+y\right)}}{y}\\
&~~~~~\small{+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln^{3}{\left(1-y^2\right)}-\ln^{3}{\left(1-y\right)}-\ln^{3}{\left(1+y\right)}-3\ln^{2}{\left(1-y\right)}\ln{\left(1+y\right)}}{3y}}\\
&=-\frac34\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{(-2)\ln{\left(1+y\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-y\right)}}{y}+\frac32\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+y\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(y\right)}}{y}\\
&~~~~~-\frac13\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln^{3}{\left(1-y\right)}}{y}-\frac{1}{12}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln^{3}{\left(1+y\right)}}{y}\\
&~~~~~+\frac13\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln^{3}{\left(1-y^2\right)}}{y}-\frac34\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(1-y\right)}\ln{\left(1+y\right)}}{y}\\
&=-\frac34\left[\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-y\right)}^{2}\right]_{0}^{1}+\frac32\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+y\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(y\right)}}{y}\\
&~~~~~\small{-\frac13\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln^{3}{\left(1-y\right)}}{y}-\frac{1}{12}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln^{3}{\left(1+y\right)}}{y}+\frac13\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln^{3}{\left(1-y^2\right)}}{y}}\\
&~~~~~-\frac18\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln^{3}{\left(1-y^2\right)}-\ln^{3}{\left(\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right)}-2\ln^{3}{\left(1+y\right)}}{y}\\
&=-\frac34\left[\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-1\right)}\right]^{2}+\frac32\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+y\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(y\right)}}{y}\\
&~~~~~-\frac13\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln^{3}{\left(1-y\right)}}{y}+\frac16\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln^{3}{\left(1+y\right)}}{y}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{5}{24}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln^{3}{\left(1-y^2\right)}}{y}+\frac18\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln^{3}{\left(\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right)}}{y}\\
&=-\frac34\left[\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-1\right)}\right]^{2}+\frac32\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+y\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(y\right)}}{y}\\
&~~~~~-\frac13\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln^{3}{\left(1-y\right)}}{y}+\frac16\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln^{3}{\left(1+y\right)}}{y}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{5}{48}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}z\,\frac{\ln^{3}{\left(1-z\right)}}{z};~~~\small{\left[y=\sqrt{z}\right]}\\
&~~~~~-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\left[\frac12\ln{\left(\frac{1+y}{1-y}\right)}\right]^{3}}{y}\\
&=-\frac34\left[\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-1\right)}\right]^{2}-\frac32\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-1\right)}-\frac32\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1-y\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-y\right)}}{y}\\
&~~~~~-\frac{11}{48}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln^{3}{\left(1-y\right)}}{y}+\frac16\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln^{3}{\left(1+y\right)}}{y}-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\left[\operatorname{arctanh}{\left(y\right)}\right]^{3}}{y}.\tag{7}\\
\end{align}$$

The first two logarithmic integrals can immediately be written as Nielsen generalized polylogarithms. It's also not difficult to reduce the third logarithmic integral to Nielsen polylogarithms:

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\left[\operatorname{arctanh}{\left(y\right)}\right]^{3}}{y}
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\left[\frac12\ln{\left(\frac{1+y}{1-y}\right)}\right]^{3}}{y}\\
&=-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln^{3}{\left(\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right)}}{8y}\\
&=-\frac14\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln^{3}{\left(x\right)}}{1-x^2};~~~\small{\left[\frac{1-y}{1+y}=x\right]}\\
&=-\frac18\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln^{3}{\left(x\right)}}{1-x}-\frac18\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln^{3}{\left(x\right)}}{1+x}\\
&=-\frac38\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(x\right)}\ln{\left(1-x\right)}}{x}+\frac38\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(x\right)}\ln{\left(1+x\right)}}{x}\\
&=\frac34\,S_{3,1}{\left(1\right)}-\frac34\,S_{3,1}{\left(-1\right)}.\tag{8}\\
\end{align}$$

This just leaves the dilogarithmic integral to evaluate.

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1-y\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-y\right)}}{y}
&=-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1-y\right)}}{y}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+yx\right)}}{x}\\
&=-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1-y\right)}\ln{\left(1+xy\right)}}{xy}\\
&=:-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{J{\left(-x\right)}}{x}\\
&=-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{S_{1,2}{\left(-x\right)}}{x}-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(-x\right)}}{x}\\
&=-S_{2,2}{\left(-1\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{4}{\left(-1\right)}.\tag{9}\\
\end{align}$$

(See Appendix 2 for definition and evaluation of the auxiliary function $J{(a)}$ used above.)

Putting everything together, we arrive at

$$\begin{align}
I_{4}
&=-\frac34\left[\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-1\right)}\right]^{2}-\frac32\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-1\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\frac32\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1-y\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-y\right)}}{y}\\
&~~~~~-\frac{11}{48}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln^{3}{\left(1-y\right)}}{y}+\frac16\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln^{3}{\left(1+y\right)}}{y}\\
&~~~~~-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\left[\operatorname{arctanh}{\left(y\right)}\right]^{3}}{y}\\
&=-\frac34\left[\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-1\right)}\right]^{2}-\frac32\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1\right)}\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-1\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac32\,S_{2,2}{\left(-1\right)}+\frac32\operatorname{Li}_{4}{\left(-1\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{11}{8}\,S_{1,3}{\left(1\right)}-S_{1,3}{\left(-1\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\frac34\,S_{3,1}{\left(1\right)}+\frac34\,S_{3,1}{\left(-1\right)}\\
&=\frac32\,S_{2,2}{\left(-1\right)}+\frac{11}{8}\,S_{1,3}{\left(1\right)}-S_{1,3}{\left(-1\right)}-\frac{7\pi^4}{480}.\\
\end{align}$$

---

**Appendix 1.**

The [Nielsen generalized polylogarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NielsenGeneralizedPolylogarithm.html) may be defined for positive integer indices via the [integral representation](http://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/PolyLog3/07/01/01/0002/)

$$S_{n,p}{\left(z\right)}:=\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+p-1}n}{n!\,p!}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{n-1}{\left(t\right)}\ln^{p}{\left(1-zt\right)}}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t;~~~\small{n,p\in\mathbb{N}^{+}}.$$

Setting $n=1$,

$$S_{1,p}{\left(z\right)}:=\frac{\left(-1\right)^{p}}{p!}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{p}{\left(1-zt\right)}}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t;~~~\small{p\in\mathbb{N}^{+}}.$$

Setting $p=1$,

$$S_{n,1}{\left(z\right)}=\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}n}{n!}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^{n-1}{\left(t\right)}\ln{\left(1-zt\right)}}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t;~~~\small{n\in\mathbb{N}^{+}}.$$

---

**Appendix 2.**

Define the real function $J:(-\infty,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ via the integral representation

$$J{\left(a\right)}:=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln{\left(1-y\right)}\ln{\left(1-ay\right)}}{y}\,\mathrm{d}y;~~~\small{a\le1}.$$

Then, for $a\le1$ we have

$$\begin{align}
J{\left(a\right)}
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln{\left(1-y\right)}\ln{\left(1-ay\right)}}{y}\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{\ln{\left(1-y\right)}}{y}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{ay}{ayx-1}\\
&=-a\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln{\left(1-y\right)}}{1-ayx}\\
&=-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{a\ln{\left(1-y\right)}}{1-axy}\\
&=-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{ax}{ax-1}\right)}}{x}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\frac12\ln^{2}{\left(1-ax\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(ax\right)}}{x}\\
&=\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln^{2}{\left(1-ax\right)}}{x}+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(ax\right)}}{x}\\
&=S_{1,2}{\left(a\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(a\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: A loooonnnnnnnnnnnggggggggggggg answer. Good job though!:-) (+1)

Comment: @Chris'ssistheartist Thanks! I'm going to take a quick break for breakfast and then have a look at the general case. :)

Comment: This is just pure beauty !! Thanks

Comment: your endurance is impressive (+1)

Comment: @tired Thank you for the compliment! It's always nice to be noticed. However, I feel like I should admit that the feat above is probably not as impressive as it might seem. I've spent a lot of time over the past few years working on various polylogarithmic integrals, and at this point I'm able to easily stitch together parts of my previous work to answer a wide variety of logarithmic integrals. ;)

Comment: @DavidH Can you kindly see [this related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3233291/more-on-the-integral-int-01-int-01-int-01-int-01-frac11x-1y-1z)?

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII I took a look the question. I'd be more than happy to attempt solution for you (I suffer from a mild addiction to polylogarithmic integrals), but I would expect a lot of the work to be just variations of the stuff I did in my answer above. What kinda complications did you run into while attempting to solve the integrals?

Comment: Integrals are not really my strength, so my input will not be much. But I'm curious about the relation between nospoon's result and yours, and how they could be stitched together.

Comment: @DavidH: You might be interested about this [new post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3233963/more-on-the-log-sine-integral-int-0-pi-theta-3-log3-left-2-sin-fra) on the Nielsen generalized polylogarithm as well.

Comment: For a long while, I missed choosing your answer (which I intended to do). Unbeatable answer!

Answer (score 8):

From [this paper](https://www.sav.sk/journals/uploads/0123134909Boyadz.pdf) page $105$ we have

$$\overline{H}_n-\ln2=(-1)^{n-1}\int_0^1\frac{x^n}{1+x}dx$$

$$\Longrightarrow (\overline{H}_n-\ln2)^4=\int_{[0,1]^4}\frac{(xyzw)^n}{(1+x)(1+y)(1+z)(1+w)}\ dx\ dy\ dz\ dw$$

now multiply both sides by $(-1)^n$ then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty$ we get

$$I=\int_{[0,1]^4}\frac{\ dx\ dy\ dz\ dw}{(1+x)(1+y)(1+z)(1+w)(1+xyzw)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(\overline{H}_n-\ln2)^4=S$$

---

Lets calculate $S$

$$S=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(\overline{H}_n-\ln2)^2\color{blue}{(\overline{H}_n-\ln2)^2}$$

$$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(\overline{H}_n-\ln2)^2\left(\color{blue}{\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{(xy)^n}{(1+x)(1+y)}dx\ dy}\right)$$

$$=\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{dx\ dy}{(1+x)(1+y)}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty(\overline{H}_n-\ln2)^2(-xy)^n\right)$$

In the same paper, page $97$  Eq$(13)$ we have

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(\overline{H}_n-\ln2)^2t^n=\frac{1}{1-t}\left(\operatorname{Li}_2(t)-2\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1+t}{2}\right)+\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\ln^22\right)$$

Therefore,

$$S=\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(-xy)-2\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1-xy}{2}\right)+\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\ln^22}{(1+x)(1+y)(1+xy)}\ dx\ dy,\qquad xy=u$$

$$=\int_0^1\int_0^x\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(-u)-2\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1-u}{2}\right)+\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\ln^22}{(1+x)(x+u)(1+u)}\ dx\ du$$

$$=\int_0^1\color{blue}{\int_u^1\frac{1}{(1+x)(x+u)}}\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(-u)-2\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1-u}{2}\right)+\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\ln^22}{1+u}\ dx\ du$$

$$=\int_0^1\color{blue}{\frac{\ln\left(\frac{(1+u)^2}{4u}\right)}{1-u}}\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(-u)-2\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1-u}{2}\right)+\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\ln^22}{1+u}\ du$$

now set $u=\frac{1-x}{1+x}$

$$\Longrightarrow S=-\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x^2)}{x}\left[\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)-2\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)+2\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\ln^22\right]\ dx$$

apply integration by parts

$$\Longrightarrow S=\frac14\ln^22\zeta(2)+\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(x^2)}{1-x^2}\left(\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}-\ln2\right)\ dx$$

The latter integral was nicely calculated by Cornel [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3506095)

$$\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(x^2)}{1-x^2}\left(\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}-\ln2\right)\ dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{6}\ln ^42-\frac{7 }{2}\zeta (4)+\frac{7}{2}\ln2\zeta (3)-\frac{3}{2}\ln ^22\zeta (2)+4 \operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

> $$\Longrightarrow S=\frac{1}{12}\ln ^42-\frac{7 }{4}\zeta (4)+\frac{7}{4}\ln2\zeta (3)-\frac{1}{2}\ln ^22\zeta (2)+2 \operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=I$$

Comment: (+1) Wonderful answer.

Comment: @ Ali Shather Good idea in your first two lines to go only "halfway" to integrals and leave the rest as a sum.

Comment: @user 1591719 Thank you.

Comment: @Dr. Wolfgang Hintze Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3233291) for explanations.

Let $I(n)=\int_{(0,1)^n} \frac{ \prod_1^n dx_i}{(1+\prod_1^n x_i)\prod_1^n (1+x_i)}$ denotes generalized integral that OP mentioned, then:

- $\small I(1)=\frac{1}{2},\ I(2)=\frac{\pi ^2}{24},\ I(3)=\frac{3 \log ^2(2)}{2}-\frac{\pi ^2}{24}$
- $\small I(4)=2 \text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{7}{4} \zeta (3) \log (2)-\frac{7 \pi ^4}{360}+\frac{\log ^4(2)}{12}-\frac{1}{12} \pi ^2 \log ^2(2)$
- $\small I(5)=-20 \text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{45}{4} \zeta (3) \log (2)+\frac{259 \pi ^4}{1440}+\frac{5 \log ^4(2)}{3}+\frac{5}{12} \pi ^2 \log ^2(2)$
- $\small I(6)=-33\zeta(\bar5,1)+60 \text{Li}_6\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+30 \text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \log ^2(2)+60 \text{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \log (2)\\\small+\frac{771 \zeta (3)^2}{64}+\frac{35}{4} \zeta (3) \log ^3(2)-\frac{29 \pi ^6}{360}+\frac{5 \log ^6(2)}{6}-\frac{5}{8} \pi ^2 \log ^4(2)$
- $\scriptsize I(7)=1729\zeta(\bar5,1)+\frac{35}{3} \pi ^2 \text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-3360 \text{Li}_6\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-420 \text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \log ^2(2)-1680 \text{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \log (2)-\frac{5397 \zeta (3)^2}{8}-\frac{315}{4} \zeta (3) \log ^3(2)+7 \pi ^2 \zeta (3) \log (2)-\frac{50813}{32} \zeta (5) \log (2)+\frac{1589281 \pi ^6}{362880}-\frac{1}{3} 14 \log ^6(2)+\frac{175}{36} \pi ^2 \log ^4(2)+\frac{4739 \pi ^4 \log ^2(2)}{1440}$

Comment: (+1) A very good paper. Thank you.

Comment: Due to an intentional sign error on my side I also found to your result for 3 dimensions.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a physicist's point of view.

As suggested by OP, i will use the simplest, geometric series approach.

Let us now look at the general case.

$$I_n=\int_0^1...\int_0^1\frac{dx_1...dx_n}{(1+x_1)...(1+x_n)(1+x_1...x_n)}$$

Let's use geometric series

$$\frac{1}{1+x_1...x_n}=1+\sum_{\nu=1}^{\infty}(-1)^\nu(x_1...x_n)^\nu$$

Now let's put the last result into $I_n$ and use the following simple result

$$\int_0^1\frac{x^\nu}{1+x}=(-1)^\nu\left [\ln2+\sum_{k=1}^\nu\frac{(-1)^k}{k}  \right ] $$
After some simple calculations(I'll skip them) we reach the end result

$$I_n=\ln^n2+\sum_{\nu=1}^\infty(-1)^{\nu(n-1)}\left [\ln2+\sum_{k=1}^\nu\frac{(-1)^k}{k}  \right ]^n$$

It is obvious that $I_n$ converges asymptotically to $\ln^n2$. Already at moderate values of $n$, $\ln^n2$ gives a good approximation.

For example,in case of $n=4$ worked out by David H if we use computed by him value $I_{4}\approx0.223076$,  absolute error, if we use $\ln^42$ instead of $I_4$, is about 0.008