# A generalization involving a logarithmic integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

In the preprint, [A note presenting the generalization of a special logarithmic integral by Cornel Ioan Valean](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/335149209_A_note_presenting_the_generalization_of_a_special_logarithmic_integral), it is given the following generalization,

> Let $n\ge1$ be a positive integer. Then,
>   \begin{equation*}
> \int_0^1 \frac{\log ^{2n-1}(x) \log(1-x)}{1+x} \textrm{d}x
> \end{equation*}
>   \begin{equation*}
> =\frac{1}{2}(2n)!\zeta (2n+1)-2\log(2)(1 -2^{-2n})(2n-1)!\zeta (2n)
> \end{equation*}
>   \begin{equation*}
> -2^{-1-2n} (2n+1-2^{1+2n})(2n-1)!\zeta(2n+1)
> \end{equation*}
>   \begin{equation*}
> -(2n-1)!\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\zeta (2k)\zeta (2n-2k+1)+2^{-2n}(2n-1)!\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}2^{2k}\zeta (2k)\zeta (2n-2k+1),
> \end{equation*}
>   where $\zeta$ represents the Riemann zeta function.

**Question 1**: Is the present generalization known in the literature? I would kindly appreciate any source with precise information.

Interestingly, on page $4$ it is presented the case $n=1$ which surprisingly can be evaluated **without** using Beta function, Polylogarithm, or Euler sums.

**Question 2:** Is it possible to proceed in the same style for other cases of the generalization or for the whole generalization and get an elegant solution **without** using Beta function, Polylogarithm, or Euler sums?

Comment: @DavidH Thank you! That would be very good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, the closed form may put in the form,

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\log ^{2n-1}(x) \log(1-x)}{1+x} \textrm{d}x$$
$$=\frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}((n+1)2^{2n+1}-2n-1)(2n-1)! \zeta(2n+1)-\log(2) (2n-1)!\zeta(2n )$$

$$-\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{2n-1}}\right)(2n-1)!\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \zeta(2k)\zeta(2n-2k+1)$$
$$+(2n-1)!\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\eta(2k)\zeta(2n-2k+1)-(2n-1)!\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \eta (2k+1)\eta (2n-2k),$$
where $\zeta$ represents the Riemann zeta function and $\eta$ denotes the Dirichlet eta function.