# Integral $\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(x^2)}{1-x^2}\left(\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}-\ln2\right)\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, closed-form, harmonic-numbers

I am trying to evaluate

> $$I=\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(x^2)}{1-x^2}\left(\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}-\ln2\right)\ dx$$

I encountered this integral while I was trying to calculate [the integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1458088/another-beautiful-integral-part-2/3505738#3505738)

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{1}{(1+x) (1+y) (1+z)(1+w) (1+ x y z w)} \ dx \ dy \ dz \ dw$$

---

First of all we can not split the integrand due to divergence, so I used $\sum_{n=1}^\infty H_n^{(2)}x^{n}=\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{1-x}$

which gives us

$$I=\sum_{n=1}^\infty H_n^{(2)}\int_0^1 \left(x^{2n-1}\ln(1+x)-\ln 2 \ x^{2n}\right)\ dx$$

$$I=\sum_{n=1}^\infty H_n^{(2)}\left(\frac{H_{2n}-H_n}{2n}-\frac{\ln2}{2n+1}\right)$$

and I don't know how to proceed. I also tried Abel's summation but it got even more complicated. any idea? All different methods are appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: May be it will be useful to use $\mathrm{Li}_{2}(x^2)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^{2k}/k^2$.

Comment: @Artem Alexandrov I do not think so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The development of a solution to the proposed integral**

I asked **Cornel** for a reduction to known integrals and series and here is a possible way to go

**First Step**

> Note that
>   $$\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(x^2)}{1-x^2}\left(\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}-\log(2)\right)\textrm{d}x$$
>   $$=\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(x^2)}{1-x^2}\left(\frac{\log((1+x)/2)}{x}+\log(2)\frac{1-x}{x}\right)\textrm{d}x$$
>   $$=\log(2)\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2\left(x^2\right)}{x(1+x)} \textrm{d}x-\int _0^1 \left(\int _x^1\frac{\text{Li}_2\left(x^2\right)}{x(1-x^2)(1+y)}\textrm{d}y\right)\textrm{d}x$$
>   $$=\log(2)\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2\left(x^2\right)}{x(1+x)} \textrm{d}x}_{\text{Reducible to known integrals and series}}-\underbrace{\int _0^1 \left(\int _0^y\frac{\text{Li}_2\left(x^2\right)}{x(1-x^2)(1+y)}\textrm{d}x\right)\textrm{d}y}_{\displaystyle \mathcal{I}}.$$

**Second Step**

> Since we have that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n H_n^{(2)} =\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{1-x}$ and $\displaystyle \int_0^1\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x}\textrm{d}x=H_{n}-H_{2n}+\log(2),$ then our integral $\mathcal{I}$ reduces to the harmonic series
>
> $$\mathcal{I}=\frac{1}{2}\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n^{(2)} }{n}\left(H_n-H_{2 n}+\log (2)\right).$$

**Third step**

> We want to apply **Abel's summation** to the last series and then we get that
>   $$\mathcal{I}=\zeta(2)-\frac{1}{2}\zeta (3)-\frac{1}{2}\log (2)\zeta (3)-\frac{23}{16}\zeta(4)-2 \log ^2(2)$$
>   $$+\frac{1}{2} \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n H_{2 n}}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{2} \underbrace{\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n H_n^{(2)}}{(2 n+1) (2 n+2)}}_{\displaystyle \mathcal{S}}.$$
>   The first series with $n$ instead of $n+1$ in denominator is calculated [here](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=2264971916932927&set=a.222846247812181&type=3&theater).

**Fourth step**

> We may recall that
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n H_n H_n^{(2)}$$
>   $$=\frac{1}{1-x}\biggr(\frac{1}{2}\log(x) \log^2(1-x)+\operatorname{Li}_3(x)+\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)-\zeta(2)\log(1-x)-\zeta(3)\biggr),$$
>   which is also found and proved in the book **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**.
>
> Thus, using this result where we replace $x$ by $x^2$, throwing a double integral over both sides in the form $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \int_0^y  f(x)\textrm{d}x\textrm{d}y$, and then rearranging and calculating the elementary resulting integrals, everything reduces to 
>   $$\mathcal{S}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n H_n^{(2)}}{(2 n+1) (2 n+2)}=\frac{5 }{4}\zeta (4)-  \log (2)\zeta (3)-\log ^2(2)\zeta (2)$$
>   $$+\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3\left(x^2\right)}{1+x} \textrm{d}x}_{\text{Reducible to known integrals and series}}+ \underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3\left(1-x^2\right)}{1+x} \textrm{d}x}_{\text{Reducible to known integrals and series}}$$
>   $$+\underbrace{ \int_0^1 \frac{\log (x) \log ^2\left(1-x^2\right)}{1+x} \textrm{d}x}_{\text{Reducible to known integrals and series}}.$$

**A first short note**: The case $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(\overline{H}_n-\log(2))^5$ may be reduced to a similar integral which can be approached in a similar style, except that we'll need to deal with weight $5$ harmonic series, and some of them might be pretty challenging like you may see in this paper [On the calculation of two essential harmonic series with a weight $5$ structure, involving harmonic numbers of the type $H_{2n}$](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/335920055).

**A second short note:** The last integral may also be viewed in the form of  a *Beta function sum* since
$$ \int_0^1 \frac{\log (x) \log ^2\left(1-x^2\right)}{1+x} \textrm{d}x=\int_0^1 \frac{\log (x) \log ^2\left(1-x^2\right)}{1-x^2}(1-x) \textrm{d}x$$
$$=\frac{1}{4} \underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\log (x) \log ^2(1-x)}{\sqrt{x} (1-x)} \textrm{d}x}_{\text{Beta function}}-\frac{1}{4} \underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\log (x) \log ^2(1-x)}{1-x} \textrm{d}x}_{\text{Beta function}},$$

and it's also good to see the second integral works nicely by letting $x\mapsto 1-x$ and using geometric series. Good to know the first integral can be finished very nicely with Cornel's *Master Theorem of Series*, and thus we avoid tedious calculations with Beta function.

**A third short note:** A good point for the second integral from the **Fourth Step** (see the final part). 
Now, if you start with integration by parts and then use the Dilogarithm reflection formula, $\operatorname{Li}_2(x)+\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)=\zeta(2)-\log(x)\log(1-x)$, you arrive at a bunch of integrals where you might also find very useful to know that 
$$ \int_0^1 \frac{\displaystyle \log(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)}{1+x} \textrm{d}x=\frac{29}{16} \zeta (4)+\frac{1}{4}\log ^2(2) \zeta (2) -\frac{1}{8} \log ^4(2),$$ which is presented and calculated in **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**, see page $17$ (also you may see a different approach [here](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=2374024339361017&set=a.222846247812181&type=3&theater)). **Also good to know this is a very important integral in the extraction process of some harmonic series with skew-harmonic numbers!**

So, it's clear now we may extract the value of $\displaystyle  \int_0^1 \frac{\displaystyle \log(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{1+x} \textrm{d}x$ by also using [Landen's Identity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LandensIdentity.html).

**Alternatively**, if you have a taste for Fourier series, we may easily arrive at the form

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3\left(1-x^2\right)}{1+x} \textrm{d}x= \frac{1}{4} \int_0^1 \frac{\log (1-x) \log ^2(x)}{x} \textrm{d}x+4\int_0^{\pi/2} x \log ^2\left(\sin(x)\right) \textrm{d}x,$$

where in the calculations I used the integral representation of the Trilogarithm you may found on page $4$ in the mentioned book. The second integral in the right-hand side is easily manageable by Fourier series and it has also been calculated here [tough definite integral: $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}x\ln^2(\sin x)~dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1640940/tough-definite-integral-int-0-frac-pi2x-ln2-sin-xdx/3292272#3292272).

So, there are at least two elegant ways to deal with

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3\left(1-x^2\right)}{1+x} \textrm{d}x.$$

> **The closed-form of a challenging auxiliary integral**
>   $$\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3\left(1-x^2\right)}{1+x} \textrm{d}x=2  \log ^2(2)\zeta (2)-\frac{23 }{8}\zeta (4)+\frac{1}{6}\log ^4(2)+4 \operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right).$$
>
> **The closed-form of the series $\mathcal{S}$**
>   $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n H_n^{(2)}}{(2 n+1) (2 n+2)}=\frac{19 }{8}\zeta (4)-\frac{1}{6} \log ^4(2)-4 \operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right).$$
>
> **The final closed-form**
>
> $$\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(x^2)}{1-x^2}\left(\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}-\log(2)\right)\textrm{d}x$$
>   $$=\frac{1}{6}\log ^4(2)-\frac{7 }{2}\zeta (4)+\frac{7}{2}\log (2)\zeta (3)-\frac{3}{2}\log ^2(2)\zeta (2)+4 \operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right).$$

Comment: Awesome (+1). I knew it its a tough integral.

Comment: you used the notation $\mathcal{I}$ for two integrals, you meant that?

Comment: @AliShather Thanks! No, it's fixed now.

Comment: do you have the final closed form?

Comment: @AliShather I'll post it soon. Just to collect and put all values of the results together.

Comment: Thank you :) I appreciate your hard work.