# A challenging integral $ -\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)}{1+x} \operatorname{Li}_2(x) \, \mathrm{d}x $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm interested in evaluating the following integral
$ \DeclareMathOperator{\Li}{Li}$

$$ \mathcal{A} = -\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)}{1+x} \Li_2(x) \, \mathrm{d}x $$

My most successful attempt thus far went like this:

First, converting the dilogarithm to its integral form yields

$$ \mathcal{A} = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x) \ln(1-xt) }{t(1+x)} \, \mathrm{d}t \, \mathrm{d}x $$

Interchanging the bounds of integration yields

$$ \mathcal{A} = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x) \ln(1-xt) }{t(1+x)} \, \mathrm{d}x \,\mathrm{d}t $$

For the inner integral, we have

$$ \mathfrak{J}(t) = \int_0^1 \frac{ \ln(1-x)\ln(1-xt) }{(1+x)} \, \mathrm{d}x $$

Differentiating under the integral with respect to $t$ and then applying partial fractions yields

$$ \mathfrak{J}'(t) = \frac{1}{1+t} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1-x) }{tx-1} \, \mathrm{d}x +\frac{1}{1+t} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)}{1+x} \, \mathrm{d}x $$

This evaluates (not) very nicely to

$$ \mathfrak{J}'(t) = \frac{1}{t(1+t) } \Li_2\left(\frac{t}{1-t} \right) +\frac{1}{1+t} \left( \frac{\ln^2(2)}{2} -\frac{\pi^2}{12} \right) $$

This means that our original integral is equivalent to solving

$$ \mathcal{A} = \int_0^1 \int_0^t \frac{1}{at(1+a)} \Li_2 \left(\frac{a}{1-a} \right) \, \mathrm{d}a \, \mathrm{d}t + \left(\frac{\ln^2(2)}{2}-\frac{\pi^2}{12} \right) \int_0^1 \int_0^t \frac{1}{t(1+a)} \, \mathrm{d}a \, \mathrm{d}t $$

The second part of the integral above is trivial, what's giving me trouble is the first part. Any help whatsoever is much appreciated!

Comment: I wonder how you wrote your MathJax code. You repeatedly used `\displaystyle` when an actual display would have been even better, and less onerous to you while typing, and you repeatedly used the `\tag` command in a way that does not result in any actual tags. (You also repeatedly put not space between f(x) and dx.)

Comment: @MichaelHardy Maybe I'm misinterpreting it's usage, but can't the command 'tag*{}' be used to center align text, I know that it's primary use is to mark equations, but can't it be also used to center align text?

Comment: It does have that effect in MathJax (I've never tried it in genuine LaTeX) but it's a lot simpler to just do the whole thing in display.

Comment: Ah, Okay. I did not not know of this, or infact of what even 'display' was. I'll keep it in mind the next time I make a post. Also, Thank you very much for the edits.

Comment: I think this type of integrals is covered by the HPL package https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0507152, which implements techniques in https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9905237, though I am not sure if the result can be cast into classical (including Nielsen's) polylogs. You may also be interested in similar integrals in section 7 of https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9806280.

Comment: As an application of the techniques in https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9905237, Mathematica with the code ``HPL = SpecialFunctions`HarmonicPolyLog; SpecialFunctions`ShuffleProductExpand[HPL[{1}, x] HPL[{2}, x]] /. HPL[{m__}, x] -> HPL[{-1, m}, 1] // Simplify`` gives $-3\mathrm{Li}_4(1/2) + 29 \pi^4 / 1440 - \log^4(2) / 8 + \pi^2 \log^2(2) / 24$, which is about 0.577998.

Comment: $-I=\frac{\pi^2}{12} \ln^22-ES(1,-1;-2)$.$ES(1,-1;-2)$ is a Level 4 MZV.And $ES(1,-1,-2)=\frac{\pi^2}{8} \ln^22
+\frac{29\pi^4}{1440} -\frac{1}{8} \ln^42
-3\text{Li}_4\left ( \frac{1}{2}  \right )$ where$ES(1,-1;-2)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 
\frac{(-1)^{n-1}H_n\widetilde{H_n}}{n^2}$ where $\widetilde{H_n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}$

Comment: the mathematica code:$\text{MZIntegrate}
\left [ \mathrm{Log}\left [1- x \right ] /(1+x)
\text{PolyLog}[2,x],\{x,0,1\}
 \right ]$ also gives the value.

Comment: Check https://www.facebook.com/photo/?fbid=2372419839521467&set=a.222846247812181 and https://www.facebook.com/photo/?fbid=2374024339361017&set=a.222846247812181

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align*}J&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-t)\text{Li}_2(t)}{1+t}dt\\
&=-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-t)}{1+t}\left(\int_0^t\frac{\ln(1-u)}{u}du\right)dt\\
&=-\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-t)\ln(1-tu)}{u(1+t)}dtdu\\
&\overset{x=1-tu,y=\frac{1-t}{1-tu}}=-\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln x\ln(xy)}{(1-x)(2-xy)}dxdy\\
&=2\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln(xy)}{(2-y)(2-xy)}dxdy-\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(xy)}{(1-x)(2-y)}dxdy\\
&=\underbrace{\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(xy)+\ln^2 x-\ln^2 y}{(2-y)(2-xy)}dxdy}_{=\text{A}}-\underbrace{\left(\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1-x}dx\right)\left(\int_0^1\frac{\ln y}{2-y}dy\right)}_{=\frac{\pi^4}{72}-\frac{\pi^2\ln^2 2}{12}}-\\&\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2 x}{(1-x)(2-y)}dxdy}_{=2\zeta(3)\ln2 }\\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\text{A}&=\underbrace{\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(xy)}{(2-y)(2-xy)}dxdy}_{u(x)=xy}+\frac{1}{2}\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(2-x)\ln^2 x}{1-x}dx}_{u=1-x}-\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(\frac{2}{2-y}\right)\ln^2 y}{y(2-y)}dy}_{u=1-y}\\
&=\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{1}{y(2-y)}\left(\int_0^y \frac{\ln^2 u}{2-u}du\right)dy}_{\text{IBP}}+\frac{1}{2}\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+u)\ln^2(1-u)}{u}du}_{=\text{B}}-\\&\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(\frac{2}{1+u}\right)\ln^2(1-u)}{1-u^2}du}_{z=\frac{1-u}{1+u}}\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{2}\left[\ln\left(\frac{y}{2-y}\right)\left(\int_0^y \frac{\ln^2 u}{2-u}du\right)\right]_0^1-\frac{1}{2}\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3 y}{2-y}dy}_{=-6\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}+\frac{1}{2}\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln(2-y)\ln^2 y}{2-y}dy}_{z=\frac{y}{2-y}}\right)+\\&\frac{1}{2}
\text{B}-\frac{1}{2}\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+z)\ln^2\left(\frac{2z}{1+z}\right)}{z}dz}_{=\text{C}}\\
&=3\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(\frac{2}{1+z}\right)\ln^2\left(\frac{2z}{1+z}\right)}{1+z}dz}_{=\text{D}}+\frac{1}{2}\text{B}-\frac{1}{2}\text{C}\\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\text{B}&=\frac{1}{6}\left(\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3(1-u^2)}{u}du}_{z=1-u^2}-\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3\left(\frac{1-u}{1+u}\right)}{u}du}_{z=\frac{1-u}{1+u}}-2\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3(1+u)}{u}du}_{z=\frac{1}{1+u}}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 z}{1-z}dz-2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 z}{1-z^2}dz+2\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 \frac{\ln^3 z}{z(1-z)}dz\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 z}{1-z}dz-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 z}{1-z}dz-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 z}{1+z}dz+2\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 \frac{\ln^3 z}{1-z}dz-\frac{1}{2}\ln^4 2\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{3}{2}\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 z}{1-z}dz}_{=-\frac{\pi^4}{15}}-\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 z}{1+z}dz}_{=-\frac{7\pi^4}{120}}-2\underbrace{\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{\ln^3 z}{1-z}dz}_{=\frac{\pi^2\ln^2}{4}-6\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{ 1}{2}\right)-\frac{21}{4}\zeta(3)\ln 2-\frac{1}{2}\ln^4 2}-\frac{1}{2}\ln^4 2\right)\\
&=-\frac{1}{144}\pi^4-\frac{1}{12}\pi^2\ln^2 2+\frac{1}{12}\ln^4 2+\frac{7}{4}\zeta(3)\ln 2+2\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{ 1}{2}\right)\\
\text{D}&=\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3\left(\frac{2}{1+z}\right)}{1+z}dz}_{u=\frac{1-z}{1+z}}+2\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln z\ln^2\left(\frac{2}{1+z}\right)}{1+z}dz}_{u=\frac{1-z}{1+z}}+\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2 z\ln\left(\frac{2}{1+z}\right)}{1+z}dz\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\ln^4 2+2\int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(\frac{1-u}{1+u}\right)\ln^2\left(1+u\right)}{1+u}du-\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+u)\ln^2 u}{1+u}du}_{=-\frac{\pi^4}{24}-\frac{\pi^2\ln^2 2}{6}+4\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{7}{2}\zeta(3)\ln 2+\frac{1}{6}\ln^4 2}+\\&\ln  2\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 u}{1+u}du}_{=\frac{3}{2}\zeta(3)}\\
&=2\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-u)\ln^2(1+u)}{1+u}du}_{=\text{E}}+\frac{1}{24}\pi^4+\frac{1}{6}\pi^2\ln^2 2-\frac{5}{12}\ln^4 2-2\zeta(3)\ln 2-4\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
\text{E}&=\frac{1}{3}\left(\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3\left(\frac{1-u}{1+u}\right)}{1+u}du}_{z=\frac{1-u}{1+u}}-\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3\left(1-u\right)}{1+u}du}_{z=1-u}+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3\left(1+u\right)}{1+u}du+3\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2\left(1-u\right)\ln(1+u)}{1+u}du}_{z=\frac{1-u}{1+u}}\right)\\
&=-\frac{7}{360}\pi^4+2\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{12}\ln^4 2+\text{D}\\
\text{D}&=\frac{1}{360}\pi^4+\frac{1}{6}\pi^2\ln^2 2-\frac{1}{4}\ln^4 2-2\zeta(3)\ln 2+2\text{D}\\
\text{D}&=-\frac{1}{360}\pi^4-\frac{1}{6}\pi^2\ln^2 2+\frac{1}{4}\ln^4 2+2\zeta(3)\ln 2
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
C&=\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3(1+z)}{z}dz}_{u=\frac{1}{1+z}}-2\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1+z)\ln z}{z}dz}_{\text{IBP}}+\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+z)\ln^2 z}{z}dz}_{\text{IBP}}-\\&2\ln 2\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1+z)}{z}dz}_{u=\frac{1}{1+z}}+2\ln 2\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+z)\ln z}{z}dz}_{\text{IBP}}+\ln^2 2\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+z)}{z}dz}_{=\frac{\pi^2}{12}}\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{4}\ln^4 2-\underbrace{\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}\frac{\ln^3 u}{1-u}du}_{=-\frac{\pi^4}{15}-\frac{\pi^2\ln^2 2}{4}+\frac{21\zeta(3)\ln 2}{4}+\frac{\ln^4 2}{2}+6\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)} \right)+2\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+z)\ln^2 z}{1+z}dz}_{=-\frac{\pi^4}{24}-\frac{\pi^2\ln^2 2}{6}+\frac{7\zeta(3)\ln 2}{2}+\frac{\ln^4 2}{6}+4\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}-\\&\frac{1}{3}\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3 z}{1+z}dz}_{=-\frac{7\pi^4}{120}}-2\ln 2\left(\frac{1}{3}\ln^3 2+\underbrace{\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}\frac{\ln^2 u}{1-u}du}_{=\frac{1}{4}\zeta(3)-\frac{1}{3}\ln^3 2} \right)-\ln 2\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 z}{1+z}dz}_{=\frac{3}{2}\zeta(3)}+\frac{1}{12}\pi^2\ln^2 2\\
&=\frac{1}{360}\pi^4+\frac{1}{12}\ln^4 2-\frac{1}{4}\zeta(3)\ln 2+2\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
A&=-\frac{1}{160}\pi^4-\frac{1}{8}\pi^2 \ln^2 2+\frac{1}{8}\ln^4 2+2\zeta(3)\ln 2+3\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
J&=\boxed{-\dfrac{29}{1440}\pi^4-\dfrac{1}{24}\pi^2\ln^2+\dfrac{1}{8}\ln^4 2+3\text{Li}_4\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 6):

The integral is immediately derived by combining the integral result at the point $i)$, Sect. $1.27$, page $17$, from the book **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series** and [Landen's identity](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LandensIdentity.html), and we get
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)}{1+x} \operatorname{Li}_2(x)\textrm{d}x=3\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{4}\log^2(2)\zeta(2)-\frac{29}{16}\zeta(4)+\frac{1}{8}\log^4(2).$$
The other resulting integral is trivial, that is $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{\log^3(1-x)}{1+x}\textrm{d}x=-6\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right).$

**End of story** (also subtler ways are possible)

*Additional information*: If also interested in the following very similar integral, $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-x)}{1+x} \operatorname{Li}_2(-x)\textrm{d}x$, one may find it calculated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3528761/evaluating-int-01-frac-ln-1-x-operatornameli-2-x1-x-dx/3528838#3528838).

Comment: The result is: $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)}{1+x} \operatorname{Li}_2(x)\textrm{d}x= -\frac{29}{1440}\pi^4-\frac{1}{24}\pi^2\ln^2 2+3\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{8}\ln^4 2$

Comment: @FDP The same result, except that I (often) find it neater to use zeta values.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
I &=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)Li_2(x)}{1+x}dx\\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{\ln x Li_2(1-x)}{2-x}dx
\overset{ibp} =-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1-x}\left(\int_0^x\frac{\ln t}{2-t} \overset{t=x y}{dt}\right)dx\\
&=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \left(  -\frac{x \ln^2x }{(1-x)(2-xy)}+\frac{2\ln x\ln y}{(2-y)(2-xy)}-\frac{\ln x \ln y} {(2-y)(1-x)}\right) dy dx \\
&=J+2K-Li_2(1)Li_2(\frac12)\tag1
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
J&=- \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{x \ln^2x }{(1-x)(2-xy)}dy dx\\
& =\int_0^1 \frac{1}{2-y}\left(\int_0^1 \frac {2\ln^2x}{2-yx}dx - \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2x}{1-x}dx\right) dy \\
&= 2 \int_0^1\frac{Li_3(\frac y2)}{y}dy
 + 2 \int_0^1\frac{Li_3(\frac y2)-Li_3(1)}{2-y}\>\overset{ibp}{dy}\\
&= 2Li_4(\frac12) - Li_2^2(\frac12)+2\ln2(Li_3(\frac12)-Li_3(1))
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
K &=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln x \ln y}{(2-y)(2-xy)}\overset{x=t/y}{dx }dy= \int_0^1 \frac{ \ln y}{y(2-y)}
\int_0^y\frac{\ln t-\ln y}{2-t}dt\>dy\\
&= \frac12 \int_0^1 \left( \frac{\ln y}y+ \frac{\ln y}{2-y}\right)\left(\int_0^y \frac{\ln t}{2-t}dt + \ln y\ln \frac{2-y}2\right)dy\\
&\overset{ibp}=-\frac1{12}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3 y}{2-y}dy+\frac14\left(\int_0^1 \frac{\ln y}{2-y}dy\right)^2
+\frac12\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2y\ln\frac{2-y}2}{2-y} \overset{y\to 2y}{dy}\\
&=\frac12Li_4(\frac12)+\frac14Li_2^2(\frac12)+\frac12\int_0^{1/2} \frac{\ln^2(2y)\ln(1-y)}{1-y}dy
\end{align}
Note

\begin{align}
&\int_0^{1/2} \frac{\ln^2(2y)\ln(1-y)}{1-y}dy\\
=& \>\ln2 \int_0^{1/2} \frac{\ln(2y^2)\ln(1-y)}{1-y}\>\overset{ibp}{dy}
 + \int_0^{1/2} \frac{\ln^2y\ln(1-y)}{1-y}\overset{y\to1-y}{dy}\\
=& 2\ln2(Li_3(1)-Li_3(\frac12))-2\ln^22Li_2(\frac12)-\frac34\ln^42 +\frac12\int_0^{1} \frac{\ln^2y\ln(1-y)}{1-y}dy
\end{align}
with
\begin{align}
&\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2x \ln (1-x)}{1-x}dx
= \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2x}{1-x}\left(-\int_0^1 \frac x{1-x y}dy\right) dx\\
=&\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-y}\left(\int_0^1 \frac {\ln^2x}{1-yx}dx - \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2x}{1-x}dx\right) dy \\
=& 2 \int_0^1\frac{Li_3(y)}{y}dy
 + 2 \int_0^1\frac{Li_3(y)-Li_3(1)}{1-y}\>\overset{ibp}{dy}
= 2Li_4(1) - Li_2^2(1)
\end{align}

Substitute the results above for $J$ and $K$ into (1) to obtain
$$I= 3Li_4(\frac12) + Li_4(1) - \frac12\left(Li_2(\frac12) + Li_2(1)\right)^2-2\ln^22 Li_2(\frac12)-\frac34\ln^42
$$

Comment: Nicely done! A minor suggestion: You should probably add \DeclareMathOperator{\Li}{Li} for better readability.